# Why do we consider the optical path length constant in a Cartesian Oval

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

I admit that this was from a homework question, but I'm having huge trouble wrapping my head around why the optical path length needs to be the same for a Lens that focuses every single ray emanating from a point to a single point:

[image: Cartesian Oval Lens]

Here, if we assume $O$ to be the origin, $P$ to be $(0,0,z_1)$ and $I$ to be $(0,0,z_2)$, the refractive indices of the two media being $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively (from left to right), then, on equating the optical path lengths for any ray of light that is incident on that surface at $(x,y,z)$, we get the equation of the surface to be:

[image: Cartesian Oval Equation]

What I can't understand is why we are equating the optical path lengths, other than the phases of every ray of light reaching point $I$ being the same.

How does it satisfy Snell's law and end up resulting in every light ray reaching the exact same point $I$?

If this is a consequence of Fermat's Principle, please explain to me how it is so, because I'm not able to understand, and everywhere I look, this seems to be taken for granted as an obvious explanation.

If this is already available in another question anywhere, please link me to it and flag as dupe.

Answer (score 1):

There are several but more or less equivalent ways one can express in one sentence all of geometrical optics. Given a piecewise differentiable scalar function $\nu(\mathcal {P})=\nu(x,y,z)$ define the ray vector $\hat {\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ as the unit tangent to a path, and define the optical length as the integral $\mathcal{L}[\mathcal{P_2,P_1}] = \int _\mathcal{P_1}^\mathcal{P_2} \nu(x,y,z) \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$ for an arbitrary path between the fixed points $\mathcal{P_1}$ and $\mathcal{P_2}$. Then:

1. Fermat's Theorem: for any first order infinitesimal variation of the path between the fixed points the variation of the optical length is also zero to a first order.
2. "Geometric" Huygens principle: Denote the infinitesimal length along a path by $d\ell = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$ then
   $d\mathcal{L} = \nu(x,y,z) d\ell$ and the rays are characterized by the vector equation $\nabla\mathcal {L}=\nu \hat {\mathbf{k}}$. Any (optical) ray, $\mathcal{P}=\mathbf{r}(\ell)$ can be equally well defined by its tangent vector $\hat {\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{d\ell}$ along the path and then these tangent vectors are the gradients to the "wavefronts", i.e., surfaces defined by $\mathcal {L}(x,y,z)= const$
3. The rays satisfy the vector equation $\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \nabla \times \hat{\mathbf{k}} =0 $ or equivalently, $\nabla \times \nu\hat{\mathbf{k}}=0$

The "more or less" equivalence of these is "just" vector analysis, the physical content is in the associated verbiage.

The existence of surfaces such that $\mathcal {L}(x,y,z)= const$ and are orthogonal to the rays defined by the equation ${\mathbf{k}} \cdot \nabla \times \hat{\mathbf{k}} =0 $ is a generalization of what is called Malus's theorem for homogeneous medium. Snell's law is just the differential expression of $\delta \mathcal{L}=0$ constrained for variations at the interface between two homogeneous media.

The statement that "ideal focusing is just equal path lengths" is from given two wavefronts $\mathcal{L}=c_1$ and $\mathcal{L}=c_2$ the optical path length betwen them is given by *any* path that can connect these two surfaces via a ray that is cut orthogonally by these surfaces, that is $\Delta\mathcal{L}[2,1]=\int_1^2 \nu d\ell$ and this integral is the *same* for *all* ray paths connecting the two wavefronts.
Of course, you can expect some mathematical difficulties as you shrink the wavefronts to a single point when trying to represent ideal focusing, and the proper handling of these singularities are outside realm of geometric optics.

Comment: My mind is blown to think that all of geometric optics can be condensed so concisely, and the answer makes sense to me for the most part, except, what if I introduce a path length difference of exactly one wavelength? Shouldn't that, following your explanation, also result in a well-focused image?

Comment: That is correct and that is how constrained waveguide lenses work, see e.g., the so-called Rotman lenses (an example http://ijarece.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IJARECE-VOL-5-ISSUE-11-2444-2458.pdf), bootlace lenses and some such. Of course , geometric optics does not know about wavelength it being the asymptotic limit of EM waves for $\lambda \to 0$