# Geometrical optics - phase considerations

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction, huygens-principle

I pasted the whole fragment from the book "Teaching Physics by Laurance Viennot". I generally understand this fragment. However, I am not sure if I understand what author means by **the phase at each of those points then has to be readjusted in order for a geometrical
optical treatment to be applied to that "object"**. I circled that fragment with blue. Can you give me more guidance how to understand that?

[image: Teaching Physics by Laurance Viennot]

Comment: As I understand the authors argument, if we consider the object plane as being in-phase, the former assumption of starting in-phase everywhere at the source can‘t hold: „rays“ have paths of different length. // This perspective may be useful when looking at the overall journey of said book, which I can‘t check.

Comment: @MS-SPO You can [borrow the book for an hour](https://archive.org/details/teachingphysics0000vien) by signing in to archive.org. Bottom of page 149.

Comment: see : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665164/why-do-we-consider-the-optical-path-length-constant-in-a-cartesian-oval/665259#665259 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200145/what-is-really-a-light-ray/200183#200183